# question about percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At the start of the new year, the price for a gallon of milk at a local grocery store increased by 2.4% as a result of inflation. If a gallon of milk cost $2.92 last year, about how much does it cost this year?

```
A.  $2.84 
B.  $2.99  
C.  $3.62  
D.  $5.32
```

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: adding i think it is a

Comment: This type of problem is better addressed at algebra.com where you can submit trivial questions and others are willing to offer a tutor-level answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If I have a number $z$, and I

> increase $z$ by $p$ percent

that means

> take $z$, and then add to it $p$ percent of $z$

Remember, the quantity "$p$ percent of $z$" is defined to be the expression
$$\frac{p}{100}\times z,$$
so that for example, $15$ percent of $200$ is
$$\frac{15}{100}\times 250=37.5.$$

Now, let $x$ be the amount that milk cost last year.

Write down the expression for $2.4$ percent of $x$:

$$\fbox{$\strut\quad\qquad^\strut_{\strut}$}$$

and add that to $x$:

$$x+\;\fbox{$\strut\quad\qquad^\strut_{\strut}$}$$

We are told that this quantity is equal to the price of milk this year: $\$2.92$. Now solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

So the price of my favorite bike was $\$100$  last year. They increased the price by $\%5$ this year. What would be the new price?

It was $\$100$  last year. What is $\%5$ of $\$100$? Note that $\%5$ is equivalent to saying $\frac{5}{100}$, so $\%5$ of $\$100$ is $\frac{5}{100} \times \$100 = \$5$. Hence, the new price is $\$100+\$5 = \$105$.

Now, you do the same thing for your question, and let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution $(2,4/100)*2,92 +2,92=2,99$!